# Groovy Script Teststep is not executed in SoapUI when I run all the steps at once

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have four test steps for a test case where, the steps has to run sequentially, I am getting some values from an API and transferring it to the actual request through a groovy script.

When I execute all the test steps of the test case, except the groovy script, all other steps are executing. Whereas, I have to manually execute the groovy script each time. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: I have tried an other way by creating plugin for soap ui in java! Thanks for the response!